# Number of ways 5 chocolates and 10 cookies can be distributed among 5 children if each child can take any number of cookies/chocolates is?

Tags: combinatorics

> Number of ways $5$ chocolates and $10$ cookies can be distributed among $5$
>   children if each child can take any number of cookies/chocolates is?

This seems really simple but I got stuck.Hints anyone? :-P

All the chocolates are identical and so are the cookies.

Comment: Any restrictions on chocolates?

Comment: First, distribute the cookies, then distribute the chocolates.

Comment: What type of restriction?No I guess not. @SchrodingersCat

Comment: @N.F.Taussig How to distribute the cookies? I could do it in case they were NOT identical :-/

Comment: Can each child take any no of chocolates?

Comment: Yes yes...let me include that in the question.. @SchrodingersCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  The number of ways we can distribute $10$ identical cookies to five children is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10$$
in the non-negative integers, where $x_k$ represents the number of cookies received by the $k$th child.  Similarly, the number of ways we can distribute $5$ identical chocolates to five children is the number of solution of the equation 
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 5$$
in the non-negative integers, where $y_k$ represents the number of chocolates distributed to the $k$th child.  Since the number of ways the cookies can be distributed is independent of the number of ways the chocolates can be distributed, multiply the results.

Comment: Got it ;-)....thank you :-D\